# Dart proxy requests to backend server during development

Tags: proxy, dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

Is there an equivalent of [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) for Dart / pub ?

In production frontend stuff is built (`pub build`) as static resources and can be served by any web server (dart-agnostic).

During development I'd like to communicate with the backend server (non-Dart), without a need to build whole frontend with `pub build` and serve it with the backend server just to see some single change in frontend code.

This feature has already been proposed, but as of now it's triaged: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16851.

It's seems that this can only be done with pub, since communicating with backend, even within the same host, is done via CORS - at least that is what's encouraged in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spend some time playing with the technology and found a solution that seems to work:
Just `pub get` and serve whole content(with subfolders!) of the `web` folder with your backend server. Then, open the page in dartium (use backend server socket address). No other servers should host the frontend code. The solution is IDE-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" way is to forward requests for Dart resources to a running `pub serve` instance which serves Dart source files or built JavaScript output (depending on the used browser) during development.

This way you don't have to cope with symlinks nor with testing on non-Dartium browsers.